# What's the purpose of Android Development device id?

Tags: android

What's the purpose of Android Development device id, under Developer Options on ICS? I've googled and found nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every device has an android device ID, the only (user) way to reset this ID is to use android's reset to factory defaults options - so this ID should remain constant unless a phone is sold/transfers ownership etc. The ID should be unique across all devices across all time.

These properties make it a very useful thing to store licences/security against.

Answer (score 2):

The device id is yet another manner that your apps can be linked to your phone. Most apps are linked to your account, but some, particularly those that you could not pay for via market, used device id so that you could not buy an app and then install it on several devices.

It used to be hidden only, and maybe after the final is out, it will be hidden again.

for more information - 
http://androidforums.com/motorola-droid-bionic/584694-ics-development-device-id.html

May be this will help you......